# UIImage Category method is not calling iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, categories

i have implemented UIImage Category...and i am trying to call a method from my viewcontroller..strangely i am getting below shown warning

[image: Waring Screen]

can anyone please answer why i am getting this warning and how to avoid that

Comment: Is *performSelector:* the method you added in the category?

Comment: @EmptyStack to _selector i am getting "e1" and e1 is the method i added in category

Comment: i created one category and included that file in my app...is there other thing that we need to do other than this like compiling

Comment: In case you forgot - Did you import the header file of your category in this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the compiler doesn't know if it needs to release the value returned by the selector. So I'm guessing you have ARC enabled, or maybe the compiler is checking this anyway as part of the static analysis stuff.

The selector may return a +1 retained object, or an autoreleased object. There is no way to know this at compile time so the compiler is giving you this warning.

Generally you should not get objects from selectors like this. The better solution would be with a strongly typed delegate interface where the memory semantics are clearer.